# Can you use PHP with XMBC?

Tags: php, media

I want to create a web interface to control which file is being played by the media server...a and possibly store information about the current song on a db. Is this something I can do with XMBC/PHP or is there some other better way to do this?

Comment: 100% off-topic. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XBMC allows for plugins written in [Python](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=HOW-TO_write_Python_Scripts_for_XBMC), there is also already a [web front-end](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=The_Web_Interface) and API. You could write your own PHP scripts to interface with the API but it's probably worth checking out the existing interface first.